# Blazor reusable component should retrieve data or not?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a doubt how to architect components within a Blazor page (in my case Server-Side, but I guess is for both models)

Is it better that the data recovery is done by the component (which therefore becomes self-sufficient) or by the caller by passing it the collection or the single entity?

It is obvious that if the component is to be called on different pages with different data, the second is mandatory.

But suppose we make a component that always uses the same data… which option is preferable?

```
<!-- Service to retrieve data is called by Component-->
<NewsList></NewsList>   
<EmployeeCard Id="1"></EmployeeCard>
```

or

```
<!-- Service to retrieve data is called by Parent-->
<NewsList ItemList="@myItemList"></NewsList>   
<EmployeeCard Employee="@myEmployee"></EmployeeCard>
```

Imagine a dashboard full of a dozen of components; even for performance reason, is it better that the dashboard makes the 12 different "await GetData()" and populate the properties or that (in parallel??) the components itself retrieve their own data?

Thanks

Comment: I usually prefer loading related data for several components, from a parent component.  (1) This avoids the "...a second operation has started on this context..." error (unless you use a Semaphore, or use short lived contexts).  (2) If you update the data of an entity in one of your child components (add/edit/delete), you can invoke a method on the parent component to 'reload' the data again -> which will update all your data across all the other child components as well.  (3)  If your different child components use the same entities (List<T>) it will be faster to load this once from parent.

Comment: Data retrieval should not be a concern of the component - pass in a parameter of the types needed (ViewModel/DTO) and then use events to the parent as Daniel has suggested.

Comment: To backup what has been said above, data belongs in View Services.  View Services get their data from Data Services. Data Services interface with the data source.  I advocate using Clean Design principles, but that is a personal choice.